# Angular is not sending the headers in the post request

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am trying to pass username to backend with my POST service and somehow it is not passing the value to the backend.

I am not able to see the username value in the request header too. I was thinking to go for the interceptor but I don't want to pass this header to the services.

What I am doing wrong here?

```ts
public service(data) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    let value = 'test';
    let data = [data];
    headers = headers.set('username', value);
    return this.http.post(`url`, data, {
        headers: headers,
        responseType: 'text'
    });
}
```

Comment: Make sure you don't override it in interceptor somehow.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a couple of things you can take a look at:

1. I believe you want your username as part of your "data", not headers. Headers should be:

   `var headers = new Headers();`

or

```
var headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json'}
```

2. the data (body) I think needs to be stringified:

   `var body=JSON.stringify(data);`
3. url should be a variable to an actual url, not a string

and then do something like this:

```
return this.http.post(url, body,{'headers':headers})
```